# How to efficiently sum paired array elements and avoid offset errors in case of pairless array?

Tags: php

Pair every two arrays is the task – store it, print it and repeat it until it becomes one value.

```
input : 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 9, 9

output: 3 7 11 17 9
        10 28 9
        38 9
        47
```

My code is working fine in this scenario. Somehow I managed to add 0 at the end for pairless elements. But my main focus is how can I make the logic even more clearer to avoid grumpy offset errors?.

My code:

```
    function sumForTwos($arr) 
{
    if(count($arr) == 1){
       exit;
    }
    else {
            $sum = [];
            for ($i = 0; $i < count($arr) -1; $i++) 
            {   
                //logic to add last array for odd count to avoid offset error
                if(count($arr) % 2 == 1){ $arr[count($arr)] = 0; }
                //logic to pair arrays
                if($i != 0) {  $i++; }
                $sum = $arr[$i] + $arr[$i + 1];
                $total[] = $sum; 
                echo $sum . " "; 
            } 
                echo "<br>";
                $arr = $total;
                //Recursion function
                sumForTwos($arr);
       }
} 
sumForTwos([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 9, 9]);
```

Comment: Are you allowed to edit the array?

Comment: yep..can give up to any number of arrays..

Comment: Create an inner loop from $j to count($arr) - $i, and inside do $arr[$i] += $arr[$i + 1] and echo it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can adopt an iterative approach and look at this as processing each level of values with every next level have 1 value less from total values. In other words, you can look at this as a breadth first search going level by level. Hence, you can use a `queue`  data structure processing each level one at a time.

You can use PHP's [`SplQueue`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.splqueue.php) class to implement this. Note that we can advantage of this class as it acts as a `double-ended queue` with the help of below 4 operations:

- `enqueue` - Enqueues value at the end of the queue.
- `dequeue`  - Dequeues value from the top of the queue.
- `push` - Pushes value at the end of the doubly linked list(here, queue is implemented as doubly linked list).
- `pop` - Pops a node from the end of the doubly linked list.

Most certainly, all the above 4 operations can be done in O(1) time.

**Algorithm:**

- Add all array elements to queue.
- We will loop till the queue size is greater than 1.
- Now, if queue level size is odd, `pop` the last one and keep it in buffer(in a variable).
- Add all pairwise elements by `dequeue`ing 2 at a time and `enqueue` their addition for next level.
- After level iteration, add the last element back if the previous level size was odd.
- Print those added elements and echo new lines for each level accordingly.

**Snippet:**

```
<?php

function sumForTwos($arr){
    if(count($arr) == 1){
        echo $arr[0];
        return;
    }
    
    $queue = new SplQueue();
    
    foreach($arr as $val){
        $queue->enqueue($val); // add elements to queue
    }
    
    while($queue->count() > 1){
        $size = $queue->count();
        $last = false;
        if($size % 2 == 1){
            $last = $queue->pop(); // pop the last odd element from the queue to make queue size even
            $size--;
        }
        
        for($i = 0; $i < $size; $i += 2){
            $first  = $queue->dequeue();
            $second = $queue->dequeue();
            echo $first + $second," ";
            $queue->enqueue($first + $second);
        }
    
        if($last !== false){// again add the last odd one out element if it exists
            echo $last; // echo it too
            $queue->push($last); 
        }
        
        echo PHP_EOL;// new line
    }
    
}

sumForTwos([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 9, 9]);
```

**Demo:** http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/5b9f6d4c9291693ac7cf204af42d1f0ed852bdf9

Answer (score 0):

Does this do what you want?

```
function pairBySums($inputArray)
{
    if (sizeof($inputArray) % 2 == 1) {
        $lastEntry = array_pop($inputArray); //$inputArray now has even number of elements
    }

    $answer = [];
    for ($ii = 0; $ii < sizeof($inputArray) / 2; $ii++) {
        $firstIndexOfPair = $ii * 2; // 0 maps to  0, 1 maps to 2, 3 maps to 4 etc 
        $secondIndexOfPair = $firstIndexOfPair + 1; // 0 maps to 1, 1 maps to 3, 2 maps to 5 etc
        $answer[$ii] = $inputArray[$firstIndexOfPair] + $inputArray[$secondIndexOfPair];
    }

    if (isset($lastEntry)) {
        array_push($answer, $lastEntry);
    }

    echo implode(' ', $answer) . "<br>";

    if (sizeof($answer) > 1) {
        pairBySums($answer);
    }
}
```

The algorithm makes sure it operates on an even array and then appends the odd entry back on the array if there is one.

```
$input = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 9, 9];
pairBySums($input);
```

produces:

```
3 7 11 17 9
10 28 9
38 9
47
```

With an even number of items,

```
$input = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 9];
pairBySums($input);
```

produces:

```
3 7 11 17
10 28
38
```